# Oracle ERROR invalid number

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
ARITHMOS KOD DATE         A B C
1        ΑΓΟ 01/08/2016   5 2 3
2        ΠΛΗ 02/08/2016   3 2 1
```

AND from netbeans program i want to insert name table and DATE AND KOD and get only the rows that meet the criteria.

Code:

```
String pote=ac3.getText();//name table

String c=((JTextField)jdt1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();//date      
String d=((JTextField)jdt2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();//date
String s0=(String)jcb1.getSelectedItem();//KOD

String sql="SELECT * FROM "+pote+" WHERE (Hmerominia BETWEEN "+c+" AND "+d+") AND KOD='"+s0+"' ORDER BY ARITHMOS";
```

if (re == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
             try{

```
    stm=(OracleStatement) conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


    rs = (OracleResultSet) stm.executeQuery(sql);
    UpdateJTable();
  /* while(rs.next()){
        v0.setText(rs.getString("ARITHMOS"));

    }*/

}
catch(Exception e1){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
}

    }else if (re == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Error showing invalid number.

Comment: What are all the variables set to - what does `sql` end up as? Andwhat is your table actually called? You should be using bind variables but that seems to bea side issue.

Comment: You are missing the single quotes around `ΑΓΟ`. Your concatenated SQL will look like `AND KOD=ΑΓΟ ORDER BY ...`, which is obviously invalid, because it will look for a column called `ΑΓΟ`. But as suggested already, you should be binding your parameters, not concatenating the values directly in the string.

Comment: I put the single quotes but now says invalid number.

Comment: And why do you think that is?  Are you going to try to debug the new error? Are you going to bind the parameters the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
public static ResultSet Consult(String consult){
       Connection conn = ConnectDB();//connection to database
        Statement declare;
        try{
            declare=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=declare.executeQuery(consult);
            return rs;
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }
       return null;

    }


}

Code in Button:
   String  pote=ac3.getText();//chosen table name
    String c=((JTextField)jdt1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();//date as varchar2 set to database table
    String d=((JTextField)jdt2.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();//date as varchar2 set to database table
    String s0=(String)jcb1.getSelectedItem();//chosen item


     String sql="SELECT * FROM "+pote+"  WHERE  Hmerominia BETWEEN '"+c+"' AND '"+d+"' AND KOD='"+s0+"'";

     int re = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "SEARCH?", "Confirm",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);


    if (re == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {



     DefaultTableModel md=( DefaultTableModel)pel300.getModel();
 md.setRowCount(0);
 rs=(OracleResultSet) Connect.Consult(sql);//Connect class

 try{
     while(rs.next()){
     Vector v=new Vector();
     v.add(rs.getString(1));
     v.add(rs.getString(2));
     v.add(rs.getString(3));
     v.add(rs.getString(4));
     v.add(rs.getString(5));
     v.add(rs.getString(6));
     v.add(rs.getString(7));
     v.add(rs.getString(8));


     md.addRow(v);
     pel300.setModel(md);


     pel300.setShowGrid(true);


     }
 }catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }

    }else if (re == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```